Python using langchain_community.utilities.sql_database.SQLDatabase to query tables outside "public" schema in PostgreSQL DB
I have a PostgreSQL DB for which I would like to use langchain to query tables (and views) that are not in the default "public" schema.
The langchain_community.utilities.sql_database.SQLDatabase.get_table_info() method generates and send the SQL DML string such as the one below, this query returns a list of tables belonging to the "public" schema.

Is there a way to make langchain aware of tables that are in other schemas other than "public" schema?
Is is there a way to make lanchain query the tables using the full table name ie schema_name.table_basename?

SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
    WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r', 'p']) AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relpersistence != 't' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != 'pg_catalog'

